# "Objects are not valid as a React child" when adding user data to Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know that how can we save user data during signup in Firestore.

```
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { collection, setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "../firebaseConfig";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const signup = async (email, password) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(
      (cred) => {
        setDoc(doc(collection(db, "users", cred.user.uid)), {
          name: "manan",
          city: "chd",
        });
      }
    );
  };

  const login = (email, password) => {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    return signOut(auth);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    login,
    signup,
    logout,
  };
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

as you can see I have created an `AuthContext.js` for all the functions. now, when in `signup()` I am not able to store the user data corresponding to their UID... as I have used

```
setDoc(doc(collection(db, "users", cred.user.uid)), {
          name: "manan",
          city: "chd",
});
```

but it is not working at all it's throwing an error

error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {error}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using both a document and a collection as a reference. you should only use a document reference on a `setDoc`

from:

```js
setDoc(doc(collection(db, "users", cred.user.uid)), {
          name: "manan",
          city: "chd",
});
```

change to:

```js
setDoc(doc(db, "users", cred.user.uid), {
          name: "manan",
          city: "chd",
});
```